# How to connect the Buttons UI?

Tags: android, user-interface, material-design

I struck in Materiel Design and need to connect those two button like the image mentioned below and when i clicked the any one button only the layout should change not the activity, so I googled for this solution but i didn't found any.Could anyone suggest me some possible solutions to achieve this UI.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You want to keep the 2 buttons and a line in buttons as well if that is the case.
Use 2 buttons widgets and keep a view between them as for lining purpose. And fro your question `one button only the layout should change not the activity`

You can try fragments. On clicking any of the buttons change fragment

Answer (score 0):

you are suppose to use Fragment with viewpager!

you just disable viewpager swipe by this `mViewPager.setPagingEnabled(false);`
 and setSelection when clicked on item

here is a cool library to implement this.[Step view](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/3711)